# Calling parent function from frame

Tags: c#, wpf

I have have a WPF application Im building with the designer. In it I have a Frame that I am loading a Page in.

To be totally honest Im lost. With a lack of instruction and ability to wrap my head around MVVM I am hoping someone might be able to help me understand how to do what I'm trying to do.

From within the page I need to call a public method 'public void UpdateTxt()'. I know this had been done a million time but I just don't understand. Most of my searches pull web/javascript results too.

I did something similar once before with two windows in a winform environment.

```
 public partial class setupApp : Form
    {
        private Form1 m_parent;


        public setupApp(Form1 frml)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            m_parent = frml;

        }
```

While the above code works in winform enabling me to locate all public functions from the parent window, I can't seem to translate it to WPF.

I have tried

```
public partial class Childpage: Page
        {
            private MainWindow m_parent;


            public Childpage(MainWindow mw1)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                m_parent = mw1;

            }
```

This throws no errors on build, but fails to break mode as soon as the debugger launches. I have no idea what the error means as well.

> No Matching Constructor Found on type

Why wont the C# back end code translate? Is there a better way?

Comment: How are you instantiating the `Page`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you set the `Source` property of the Frame in xaml code like this:

```xml
<Frame Source="SamplePage.xaml"/>
```

in this case you need add a parameter-less constructor to your page.

```
public partial class SamplePage
{
    private MainWindow _parentWindow;

    public SamplePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public SamplePage(MainWindow parentWindow) : this()
    {
        _parentWindow = parentWindow;
    }
}
```

But if you want pass the parent window to child page you can set the Frame content in code-behind. like this:

```
SampleFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new SamplePage(this));
```

in this case you don't need to parameter-less constructor.

Comment: Your absolutely right that I set the frame source that way. Thank you for pointing out that the parameter was the problem there. I think I understand it to mean that the two declarations were conflicting. 

Thank you for your guidance